# GitHub API Custom Headers C#

Tags: c#, request, github-api

I'm trying to get some data about commits from GitHub API. When I add custom headers to the request, API seems to be ignoring them.

```
public string MakeRequestGitHub(string url, Dictionary<string, string> params = null)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/vnd.github.v3+json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0";
        request.Headers["Time-Zone"] = "Europe/Prague";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

API still returns bad datetime. Also happens when I add Authorize header:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorize", "token mytoken");
```

API will not authorize me. I have to add access_token to url as param.
What can be wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by a `bad datetime`?

Comment: UTC instead of proper time of Timezone.